Adjusting DataGridView scroll behavior to change number of rows per scroll event in VB.NET
I'm working on a VB.NET application where I have a DataGridView on my form. I've noticed that by default, the DataGridView scrolls 3 rows per scroll event. However, I want to change this behavior to scroll only 1 row per event.
I've tried handling the DataGridView's scroll event and setting DataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell to achieve the desired behavior. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't provide smooth scrolling, and the DataGridView's behavior becomes erratic.
Could someone please guide me on how to properly adjust the scroll behavior of the DataGridView so that it scrolls 1 row per scroll event smoothly?
Thank you in advance for any assistance

You could use a Custom Control, overriding the default WM_MOUSEWHEEL behavior, something like this: How can I scroll a ListView by one row instead of the default three using the mouse wheel?. In that case, of course TopItem.Index becomes FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex and you can check the CurrentCell.ColumnIndex to then re-set the FirstDisplayedCell to the new calculated Column / Row indexes. Also, call MyBase.WndProc(m) in the Case Else section only

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This question is similar to: How can you make a DataGridView scroll one item at a time using the mouse wheel?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have found that for each scroll, the scroll event fires 3 times.. so the problem had to do with this. Thanks for the answer
